# is pip install scipy fails with ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

Tags: macos, python

I am trying to install python scipy in a virtual environment using

```
pip install scipy
```

It fails with the following error

...

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

error: Command "/usr/local/bin/gfortran -Wall -L/usr/X11/lib build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-2.7/build/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-2.7/scipy/fftpack/_fftpackmodule.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-2.7/scipy/fftpack/src/zfft.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-2.7/scipy/fftpack/src/drfft.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-2.7/scipy/fftpack/src/zrfft.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-2.7/scipy/fftpack/src/zfftnd.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-2.7/build/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-2.7/scipy/fftpack/src/dct.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-2.7/build/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-2.7/scipy/fftpack/src/dst.o build/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-2.7/build/src.macosx-10.9-x86_64-2.7/fortranobject.o -L/usr/local/Cellar/gfortran/4.8.2/gfortran/lib/gcc/x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0/4.8.2 -Lbuild/temp.macosx-10.9-x86_64-2.7 -ldfftpack -lfftpack -lgfortran -o build/lib.macosx-10.9-x86_64-2.7/scipy/fftpack/_fftpack.so" failed with exit status 1